# Trying to create a HashMap after reading data from file. Getting null values. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer, hashmap

I am trying to read from a file to create a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>`.

The inputFile is in the following format:

```
 A    B    C    D
 1   -1    2   -3
 2    3   -5    3
-3    2    7   -5
 4    3    1    1
```

This input file represents distances between all pairs of points. Which means, it represents the following matrix:

```
     A    B    C    D
A    1   -1    2   -3
B    2    3   -5    3
C   -3    2    7   -5
D    4    3    1    1
```

While creating the map, when I print the keys and values, the correct values are printed. But when I try printing the map after populating it completely, it only prints the keys of the outer map correctly. Everything else is printed as `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> initMap() {
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> distancesMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>(); 
    final String distancesFileName = "/home/name/workspace/Tester/src/main/distances.txt";
    String distancesFile = Main.readInputFile(distancesFileName);
    String[] distancesFileArray = distancesFile.split("\n");
    String[] firstLine = distancesFileArray[0].split("\t");
    for(int iii = 1; iii < distancesFileArray.length; iii++) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] singleLineArray = distancesFileArray[iii].split("\t");
        for(int jjj = 0; jjj < singleLineArray.length; jjj++) {
            tempMap.put(firstLine[jjj], Integer.parseInt(singleLineArray[jjj]));
            // the following print statement (commented out) prints the correct values  
            // System.out.println(firstLine[jjj] + " " + tempMap.get(firstLine[jjj]));

        }
        distancesMap.put(firstLine[iii - 1], tempMap);
    }
    /*
     * The following lines just print the key of the outer map correctly
     * but everything else is printed as null
     */
    for(String key : distancesMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.print(key + "\t");    // prints the correct String value
        HashMap<String, Integer> tempMap = distancesMap.get(key);
        for(String innerKey : tempMap.keySet()) {
            // the following line only prints null values
            System.out.print(tempMap.get(innerKey + "\t"));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return distancesMap;
}
```

The output I get from this is like:

```
B    nullnullnullnull
C    nullnullnullnull
D    nullnullnullnull
A    nullnullnullnull
```

Comment: Had you named your maps to something more concrete, you wont have had run into this problem :-)

Comment: @ Bonz0 : You asked a valid question, with a code. You should be okay.  Please accept the answer if it worked for you.  (You may delete the question if you really do not want to refer it again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.print (tempMap.get (innerKey + "\t"));
```

to

```
System.out.print (tempMap.get (innerKey) + "\t");
```

Comment: I... Oh my god...

**Edit:** I cannot believe I spent 90 minutes trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.